# PHP: Error Message if user searches for non-existent item

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to display an error message if a user searches for something I have not written a rule for. This is what I mean.

The user will have a searchbar with a submit button. He will enter a word and hit submit. 
I have written rules for four specific words. They assign a value to the word.

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search ['A'] = "32";
$search ['B'] = "30";
$search ['C'] = "34";
$search ['D'] = "53";

if ($_POST['search'] == A)
{print 'A has a value of ' . $search['A'] . ' dollars.';}
```

Etc... a similar rule is written for B, C, and D.

**Now I need code that will display an error message if the user searches for anything other than A, B, C, or D.** I wrote the following line of code, but it did not work. It displayed the message everytime, even when the user searched for A B C or D.

```
if ($search != 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D')
    {print $_POST['search'] . ' was not found in our database.';}
```

I want a line of code that will display a message if the user searches for anything that is not A B C or D.

Comment: if there's only 4 option give then a select box so they have no option to pick anything but 1 of the 4. Far friendlier to a user.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if ($search != 'A' &&  $search != 'B' &&  $search !=  'C' &&  $search !=  'D')
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know of would be:

```
 switch ($_POST['search']) {
    case 32:
        //do something
        break;
    case 30:
        //do something
        break;
    case 34:
        //do something
        break;
    case 53:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        //They enetered something else, do something
}
```

Or you could do something like:

```
$values = array('A' => 32, 'B' => 30, 'C' => 34, 'D' => 53);
```

Then:

```
if (!in_array($_POST['search'], $values) { 
    // they entered something else
} else {
    switch ($_POST['search']) {
        case 32: //do something
        case 30: //do something else
        ETC...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try something like this with switch statement:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$num = 0;
switch ($search) {
    case 'A':
        $num = 32;
        break;
    case 'B':
        $num = 30;
        break;
    case 'C':
        $num = 34;
        break;
    case 'D':
        $num = 53;
        break;
    default:
        $num = 0;
}
if ($num) {
    echo 'A has a value of ' . $num . ' dollars.';
} else {
    echo $_POST['search'] . ' was not found in our database.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax/post here very easily.
for example : ur jquery code :

```
  ("#sub_btn").click(function(){
    var  url = 'http://localhost/example/test';// ur method  url
    var search_str = $("#seach_txt").val(); // seach text box id 
    if(search_str == '' || search_str == 'undefined' )
    {
          $("#msg").html("Please enter value "); //
    }else{
        $.post(url,{data:search_str},function(responses){
             $("#msg").html(responses); //div with id msg
         });

    }

  });

  //ur php code
        function test(){

        $search ['A'] = "32";
        $search ['B'] = "30";
        $search ['C'] = "34"; 
        $search ['D'] = "53";
      if( $_POST['data'] == 'A' || $_POST['data'] == 'B' || $_POST['data'] ==   'C' ||  $_POST['data'] == 'D' ){

        if(array_key_exists($_POST['data'],$search)){
          echo $_POST['data'].' has a value of ' . $search['.$_POST['data'].'] . ' dollars.';exit;

        }else{
         echo $_POST['data'].' not found in our database';exit;
        }
  }
```

}

```
       //ur html 

       <div id="msg"></div>
       <input type="text" id="search_txt" />
        <input type="button" id ="sub_btn" value="Submit">
```

Hope this is helpful for u!!
  Thanks.